# how to scroll a Tix ScrolledWindow

Tags: python, scrolledwindow, tix

Using Python, how can I programmatically scroll (not using the scrollbars) the window in a Tix ScrolledWindow? The normal way would be to call xview / yview, but those calls do not seem to be available. Googling suggest that it is not possible at all, but I hope for something better.

Answer (score 0):

```
st = tix.ScrolledText(parent)
st.text.see('end')
```